# In electron how to send custom header and value for every request?

Tags: electron

I use electronjs for building a cross platform desktop application. I would like to send a custom header with a value for every request from electron. Initially in loadURL(), i could use extraHeaders to set the custom header. How to send it in all subsequent requests?

Comment: What lib do you use to make the requests?

Comment: I use electron's webRequest object. _i.e. webRequest = window.webContents.session.webRequest;_ Do you recommend using any lib ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As recommended by the [documentation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/web-request), you should use `session` object and the method `onBeforeSendHeaders`:

```
const { session } = require('electron')

// Modify the user agent for all requests to the following urls.
const filter = {
  urls: ['https://*.github.com/*', '*://electron.github.io']
}

session.defaultSession.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders(filter, (details, callback) => {
  details.requestHeaders['User-Agent'] = 'MyAgent'
  callback({ requestHeaders: details.requestHeaders })
})
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to work for me

Comment: hello @EmmanuelMurairi, without code is very dificult see why it is not working.